# Plot ROC in R for a GLM model

Tags: r, roc

```
pred1 <- prediction(predictions=glm.prob2,labels = train_data)
```

> error: Error in prediction(predictions = glm.prob2, labels = train_data) : 
>     Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run.

I have used glm model to predict the output and trying to produce pred1 as a variable for plotting the ROC curve.

Here is  the full code

```
View(train_data)
library(ROCR)
pred1 <- prediction(predictions=glm.prob2,labels = train_data)
perf1<-performance(pred1,measure ="TP.rate",x.measure = "FP.rate")
plot(perf1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and write a problem description. What are you doing? What programming language is this - add the relevant tag(`R`)! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please don't type in ALL CAPS here. It's considered to be SHOUTING here, just like everywhere else on the internet. There's no reason to shout to get attention; people are very good at seeing, reading and answering questions here without any need to shout.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, please include a minimum reproducible example to include a subset of your data (for example using `dput`). We need to be able to cut and paste your code into our own R sessions, get it to run, and explore solutions so we can verify them and present the results to you with an explanation. Thanks :)